# For loop and paste() to merge multiple dataframes in R

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I have multiple identical dataframes: X1, X2, ..., X32

example of one dataframe:

```
> X1
    value
1 3300320
```

I would like to have juste one dataframe like that:

```
> XTotal
    value   X
1 3300320   1
2  345098   2
...
32  34355   32
```

I tried with a for loop and paste("X", i, sep=""), rbind, etc. but each time I got a list of string like that:

```
> listDF
1  "X1"
2  "X2"
...
32 "X32"
```

So, I can't call properly each dataframe to put their values in the XTotal dataframe...

I'm a little lost, any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never grow an object in a loop. This is highly inefficient as it will copy the entire object every time.

to create a list of the data.frames use `get` and `lapply` or `mget`

```
dflist <-  mget(paste('X', 1:32), envir = parent.frame()) 
# also valid
# dflist <- lapply(paste('X', 1:32), get)

# to combine them
DFlist <- do.call('rbind', dflist)


# or, faster
library(data.table)
DFlist <- rbindlist(dflist)
```

If the data.frames do not have the same columns / order of columns use `rbind.fill` from `plyr`

```
library(plyr)
DFlist <- rbind.fill(dflist)
```

There really isn't any need to create `dflist` explicity

Any of the  following would also work

```
rbind.fill(mget(paste('X', 1:32), envir = parent.frame()))
rbindlist(mget(paste('X', 1:32), envir = parent.frame()))
do.call(rbind, mget(paste('X', 1:32), envir = parent.frame()))
```

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! I didn't know the mget fonction.